# JQuery If condition (specific for a content slider)

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements, jquery-animate, conditional-operator

I am new at JQuery and I have a specific question about the IF-THEN-ELSE fork.
The big problem for me is the syntax of this (I suck at Javascript). It would help me if anyone can "translate" the pseudo code into a JQuery (or Javascript) valide code.

The pseudo code:

**IF** "#Contentshowroom" css "left" is NOT > 1960px

**THEN** 
On Click "#Forwardbutton" DO 
animate "#Contentshowroom" css "left" =+980px

**ELSE** You can not click on the "#Forwardbutton"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[click doc](http://api.jquery.com/click/)
[animate doc](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)
[offset doc](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

```
$("#Forwardbutton").click( function( e ){

   // lookup is safe, no noticable performance cost.
   // though a reference makes it more losely coupled.
   // I'll leave it at your discretion.
   var target = $("#Contentshowroom")
   // NOTE: the offset parent should have position relative or absolute.
   , leftPos = target.offset().left; 

   if ( leftPos < 1960 ) {

      target.animate({
         left : leftPos + 980
      }); // see docs to tweak animation

   } // else do nothing.

} );
```

Could also use `e.preventDefault();` , but don't if it's not needed, it will safe you headaches if you add more listeners to your buttons and find out they're not working.

Comment: I think your note about not using `.css()` is right. If the `left` isn't set using CSS, you may get `auto` instead of the position, which your double bitwise NOT operator will translate into `0`.

Comment: @patrick offset() is better, does less in the background, so changed it completely. BITWISE NOT is actually nice to use if you write low level javascript without a framework, but jQuery is used so I better leave it out.

Answer (score 2):

Place the if() statement in the click handler for `#Forwardbutton` to test the left position of `#Contentshowroom`.

If you're using jQuery:

```
$('#Forwardbutton').click(function() {
    var $Content = $('#Contentshowroom');
    if( $Content.offset().left <= 1960 ) {
        $Content.animate({ left: '+= 980' });
    }
});
```

So now when you click the `Forwardbutton`, it will check the left `.offset()` position of the `Contentshowroom` to see if it is less than or equal to `1960px`. And if so, it will animate the left position an additional `980px`.

[jQuery's `.offset()` method](http://api.jquery.com/offset) gives you the `top/left` positions relative to the `body`. If you want it relative to its parent container, then use [jQuery's `.position()` method](http://api.jquery.com/position/).

Comment: +1 but, i would also add ... `function(e) { e.preventDefault() });`

Comment: @aSeptik - Certainly worth noting, but we're not entirely certain what is being clicked, so it may not be necessary. Wouldn't hurt though. :o)

Comment: +1 same .offset() idea, you might've been first to mention it, I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

```
// first store contentShowroom and it's left property to save getting > 1
var contentShowroom = $('#Contentshowroom');
var showroomLeft = contentShowroom.css('left');
var forwardButton = $('#Forwardbutton');

if (showroomLeft <= 1960){
  forwardButton.click(function(){
    contentShowroom.animate({left: showroomLeft + 980);
  }
}
else {
  forwardButton.unbind('click');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if this is to be run once at the beginning then

```
if ( $('#Contentshowroom').offset().left > 1960 )
{
  $('#Forwardbutton').click( function(){
    $('#Contentshowroom').animate({left:'+=980'});
  } );
}
else
{
  // if the #Contentshowroom is a link then 
  $('#Contentshowroom').removeAttr('href');
  // if the #Contentshowroom is a button then 
  // $('#Contentshowroom').attr('disabled',true);
}
```